# Unable to disable Hibernate log messages

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j

I'm using Hibernate for a personal project.
In my project, I have these directory:

+ conf
   log4j.properties
+ bin
  *my classes*

Using Windows console, I go to project directory (the parent of bin and conf) and I start the application with a command like this:

`java -cp conf;lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar;[etc] com.moc.Main`

My log4j.properties file is this (taken from an hibernate example):

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=error
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl=error
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker=error
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator=error
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=error
```

On application start, this is the output:

```
2010-11-06 19:00:56,376 - Logger.getRootLogger().info() statement
12 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.3-Final
13 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
16 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
20 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
108 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: com/moc/hibernate.cfg.xml
108 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: com/moc/hibernate.cfg.xml
124 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from file: conf\hiber\Customer.hbm.xml
.
.
.
and so on
.
.
.
795 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
795 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
```

The color of Hibernate log lines is red, my log lines are black.

Why I still see INFO output from Hibernate? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hibernate uses SFL4J for logging. What JARs do you have exactly on your classpath? What SFL4J binding? Do you only have log4j as logging backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way of checking your log4j configuration and the events occuring at runtime is adding 
**-Dlog4j.debug** option to the java command line.  In your case it will become:

```
java  -Dlog4j.debug -cp conf;lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar;[etc] com.moc.Main
```

This will throw information on console of the sequence of loading of log4j configuration. You can then determine if your log4j.properties is getting loaded correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your log4j configuration looks ok, is your log4j.properties file on the classpath and in the root package? I.e. is it in the root of conf, lib1.jar, lib2.jar pr any other jar/directory in your classpath?

Try this to check if the file is being loaded correctly.

On this line:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
```

chage to

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout
```

This will set the log level for the root logger and hence all loggers to ERROR, if you are still seeing the INFO log entries then your log4j.properties file must not be loading correctly, most likely for the reasons stated above.

Comment: My application is able to see the log4j.properties because with an error level for rootLogger I can't see my Logger.getRootLogger().info("hello"); - 
To load the conf file I use PropertyConfigurator.configure("conf/log4j.properties"); as first step of my application. log4j.properties is in conf/log4j.properties. I tried to put it in bin (see my dir hierarchy in my post) but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this syntax instead?

```
log4j.category.org.hibernate=ERROR
```