# Disable Hibernate output

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, desktop-application

I'm working on Java desktop application which uses Hibernate 3. Everything works fine, but when I run my application, my output is flooded with lines like:

```
mar 20, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
mar 20, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5
mar 20, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
mar 20, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
mar 20, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
mar 20, 2013 8:26:07 PM org.hibernate.ejb.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate EntityManager 3.3.2.GA
mar 20, 2013 8:26:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: persistence.Document
mar 20, 2013 8:26:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Document.findAll => SELECT d FROM Document d
mar 20, 2013 8:26:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Document.findById => SELECT d FROM Document d WHERE d.id = :id
mar 20, 2013 8:26:08 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: Document.findByUrl => SELECT d FROM Document d WHERE d.url = :url
mar 20, 2013 8:26:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity persistence.Document on table DOCUMENTS
mar 20, 2013 8:26:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: persistence.LanguageEntry
mar 20, 2013 8:26:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: LanguageEntry.findAll => SELECT l FROM LanguageEntry l
mar 20, 2013 8:26:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder bindQuery
INFO: Binding Named query: LanguageEntry.findById => SELECT l FROM LanguageEntry l WHERE l.id = :id
```

How can I disable it? Will be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: It's in one of the xml files or in `log4j.properties`

Answer (score 1):

See the prior answer below:

[Unable to disable Hibernate log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114410/unable-to-disable-hibernate-log-messages)

It looks like it might be as easy as adding -Dlog4j.debug option to the java command line at runtime.

Comment: I didn't add log4j library to my project - it is added by default together with hibernate? I tried adding the option you suggested, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hmm See the last post on this page: [LINK](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2402646) "Hibernate is using slf4j log facade now, to bridge to log4j, you need to put log4j and slf4j-log4j12 jars to your lib and then the log4j properties will take control Hibernate logs."

Comment: @user1315305 did you ever get this cleared up?

Comment: No, I had also some other issues and decided to try EclipseLink instead, and so far I'm satisfied. But anyway, thank you for your advices.

Comment: @user1315305 Good deal. Don't forget to up vote for helpful advice! ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to put  `hibernate.show_sql = false` in hibernate properties

Comment: But how can I do that? I'm not really familiar with log4j - where can I find this .properties file?

Comment: @user1315305 do you have any log4j.properties file

Comment: I didn't create any. Is it created somewhere by default? The IDE I'm using is Netbeans 7.2, if that matters.

Comment: i updated my answer see once

Comment: I tried it already - didn't help.